# How copy part of int array to another int array in C/C++?

Tags: c++

please can you help me?
How can I copy part of one int array to another int array?

Example:

```
typedef struct part {
  int * array;
} PART;

int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
PART out[] = new PART[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  memcpy((char *)array[i * 3], (char *)out[i].array, 3 * sizeof(int));
}
```

But this don't working... :(

Comment: besides the answer below, your use of `memcpy` is probably wrong. the first argument of `memcpy` is the _destination_, not the source.

Comment: I see your question has C++ tag, if so, don't uglify your code with "typedef struct" and don't use memcpy, C++ has std::copy for that. It's also a good idea to use ALL_CAPS names for macros only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok you have 3 problems.

1. You are casting an int to a char* `(char *)array[i * 3]`

   What you really mean is `(char *)&array[i * 3]`.  ie take the address of the i*3th element.
2. you are trying to copy data from an uninitialised array.

   you should allocate memory to out[i].array.
3. You appear to have your memcpy the wrong way round.

The following code will work better:

```
typedef struct part {
  int * array;
} PART;

int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
PART out[] = new PART[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  out[i].array = new int[3];
  memcpy( (char *)out[i].array, (char *)&array[i * 3], 3 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Make sure you remember to delete[] the memory allocated to out[i].array ...

Comment: Thank you, in fact, in real problem, I initialise array in struct and use memcpy with right order of arguments, problem was in "&".
Thank you again, stupid mistake... :)

Comment: @Sebastian:  If the answer solves your problems feel free to accept my answer by clicking the "tick" in the top left of my post :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for `* array` before doing `memcpy`.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct part {
    int * array;
} PART;

int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
PART out[] = new PART[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     out[i].array = malloc(9*sizeof(int));
     // will copy 9 array values into out[i].array
     memcpy(out[i].array, array, 9 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: More specifically, you have an array of PARTs. The `int *array` inside that struct is uninitialized. It must be initialized.

Comment: erm. I think he just needs 3 `int` s in each `PART`.

Comment: Isn't he OP trying to copy the whole array on every `PART`?

Answer (score 1):

The struct part of this is kind of irrelevant.  What you are trying to do can be accomplished this way:

```
int src[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int part[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::copy(src + (3 * i), src + (3 * (i + 1)), part[i]);
}
```

An even better solution can be done by using `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays:

```
std::vector<int> a(src, src + 9);
std::vector<std::vector<int> > b;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> c(a.begin() + (3 * i), a.begin() + (3 * (i + 1)));
    b.push_back(c);
}
```